# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when printing the reverse of an array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

When running it in cmd it shows error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at Reverse.main(Reverse.java:18)

My code is

```
import java.util.*;
class Reverse
{
    public static void main (String agrs[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int a,r,s;
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        r= sc.nextInt();
        int num[]=new int[r];
        for (a=0;a<r;a++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Number: "+(a+1)+":");
            num[a]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("\n Displaying number in reverse order\n-----------\n");
        for (a= num[a]-1;a<0;a--)
        {
            System.out.println(num[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am new to java, I am confused about how to fix this.

Comment: I would strongly suggest making a habit of using more descriptive variable names. It helps make your code much easier to read.

Comment: thanks  Dragondraikk i will keep it in mind the next time i write a code.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here:

```
for (a= num[a]-1;a<0;a--){
    System.out.println(num[a]);
}
```

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means the array does not have an index of `num[a] - 1`.

Try this instead:

```
for (a = r - 1; a >= 0; a--){
    System.out.println(num[a]);
}
```

Or use `num.length - 1`:

```
for (a = num.length - 1; a >= 0; a--){
   System.out.println(num[a]);
}
```

Comment: or to stay in his schema use `num.length -1`

Comment: @MuratK. Thanks. I have added that into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You solved the problem thanks to mmking's answer.

Now let's think about how to print the reverse of an array using java 8 features.

*Use of numeric Stream*

```
int num[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
IntStream.range(1, num.length + 1).boxed()
        .mapToInt(i -> num[num.length - i])
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Use of `Collections.reverseOrder`*

```
Stream.of(5, 6, 7, 8).sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Use of `descendingIterator`*

```
Stream.of(5, 6, 7, 8).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
        .descendingIterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
8
7
6
5
```